# CORS error occurs when establishing a restAPI in springboot

Tags: java, angular

trying to connect my RestAPI(SpringBoot) to angular but there's this cors error which does not allow the connection to happen.
the error in the front end side is

## "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/hello-world-bean/path-var/root. (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed)."

And one more thing i am using the SpringBootSecurity Service by adding a username and password in application.properties file.

I tried to use Filter, WebMvcConfigurer, WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter but i am not in luck.

```
 executeHelloWorldBean(){
        return this.http.get<HelloWorldBeans>("http://localhost:8080/hello-world-bean/");
      }
      executeHelloWorldBeanWithParameter(name){
        let basicAuthString = this.createBasicAuthenticationHeader();
        let headers = new HttpHeaders({
             Authorizaton : basicAuthString
          })  
          return this.http.get<HelloWorldBeans>(`http://localhost:8080/hello-world-bean/path-var/${name}`,
          {headers})
      }
      createBasicAuthenticationHeader(){
        let username='root'
        let password ='password'
        let basicAuthString = 'Basic ' + window.btoa(username + ':' + password)
        return basicAuthString}}
```

```
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityBasicAuth implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins(
                        "http://localhost:4200")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD")
                .allowCredentials(true)
        ;
    }

}
```

I just want my RestApi to be connected to my FrontEnd

Comment: Did you checked the .htaccess configurations, and if the origin of both request and response ends are same or not.. I mean there can be difference of http:// and https://

Comment: usually cors is something you ahve to set up in the backend api so ID recommend checking if that works (fo rexample trying an ajax from the console after the site loads(or even plain XMLHttpRequest)) to make sure its not blocked by that on top of that Im pretty sure angular has some very tight security settings that block requests as well if its just for localhost/testing there should be a setting in the browser flags to loosen the security up a bit

Comment: I haven't created .htaccess file yet zaid. I am just locally checking the connection between angular front end code and my rest API. The problem started popping up after I set the application.properties with username and password  in spring application